# onClick image, display div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to javascript but i wanted to know how to do something in it. Basically i have 3 image buttons. I want to know how i can make it so when you click the first button a div shows up, then when you click the next button the div that is present disappears and the next div shows up for button two in its place. By divs i mean any content that i put inside of it. Just like the tabs on a website, when you click one you get a page. Then when you click the next tab the previous page disappears and the next page is shown. Instead of pages these would be divs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? There are a myriad of ways to do this. Kind of hard to know what you are trying to do without knowing what you are using. You can use pure javascript for this or you can use one of the many libraries you have available to you.

Comment: Have u tried anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple solution for hide and show related div's

Check the link for solution : http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/rny2wb5z/34/

HTML:

```
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" data-id="divId1"/> 
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" data-id="divId2"/> 
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" data-id="divId3"/>
 <div id="divId1" class="hideDivs">Div 1</div>
 <div id="divId2" class="hideDivs">Div 2</div>
 <div id="divId3" class="hideDivs">Div 3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("img").on('click',function(){
   var hello = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.hideDivs').hide();
   $('#'+hello).show();
 });
```

CSS:

```
 .hideDivs{
    display:none; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign IDs to the divs, then set their visibility with a function. You can call this function with the onClick attribute of the image button.

Javascript:

```
function changePage(newPageId) {
    //hide all pages
    document.getElementsByClassName("selectablePages").style.display = 'none';
    //show page we want to see
    document.getElementById(newPageId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Html:

```
<img src="p1.gif" alt="page1" onclick="changePage('page1')" />
<img src="p2.gif" alt="page2" onclick="changePage('page2')" />
<img src="p3.gif" alt="page3" onclick="changePage('page3')" />

<div id="page1" class="selectablePage">asdasdasd</div>
<div id="page2" class="selectablePage">jghjghjghj</div>
<div id="page3" class="selectablePage">utytyutyuty</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rny2wb5z/2/)

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" id="imgId1"/> 
<div id="divId1" class="hideDivs">Div 1</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" id="imgId2"/> 
<div id="divId2" class="hideDivs">Div 2</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHoSf.gif?s=128&g=1" id="imgId3"/> 
<div id="divId3" class="hideDivs">Div 3</div>
```

//jQuery

```
$("#imgId1").click(function(){
    $("#divId2").hide();
    $("#divId3").hide();    
    $("#divId1").show();
});
$("#imgId2").click(function(){
    $("#divId1").hide();
    $("#divId3").hide();    
    $("#divId2").show();
});
$("#imgId3").click(function(){
    $("#divId1").hide();
    $("#divId2").hide();    
    $("#divId3").show();
});
```